# Configurar nueva BD dentro de database.php desde la misma aplicación en Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, mysqldb

Agradezco la ayuda, estoy creando un sistema multicliente, pero voy creando en runtime las bases de datos de los mismos, y a la vez utilizo la bd maestra, ya logro crear la bd, pero no sé cómo puedo configurarla dentro del database.php o env.php para usarla (esto es corriendo la aplic), y poder volver a usar la bd maestra cuando lo necesite.

Comment: Para que se entienda mas la pregunta editala y muestra el código de tu configuración

Answer (score 1):

se me ocurren al menos 3 formar de modificar los valores de los archivos de `config/database.php` en el momento de ejecución (runtime):

```
/** Opcion 1 usando la Facade Config */
\Config::push('database.connections.mysql2.driver', 'mysql');
\Config::push('database.connections.mysql2.host', '127.0.0.1');
\Config::push('database.connections.mysql2.port', '3306');
\Config::push('database.connections.mysql2.database', 'DATABASE_MYSQL2_NAME');
\Config::push('database.connections.mysql2.username', 'DATABASE_MYSQL2_USERNAME');
\Config::push('database.connections.mysql2.password', 'DATABASE_MYSQL2_PASSWORD');
\Config::push('database.connections.mysql2.unix_socket', '');
\Config::push('database.connections.mysql2.charset', 'utf8mb4');
\Config::push('database.connections.mysql2.collation', 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci');
\Config::push('database.connections.mysql2.prefix', '');
\Config::push('database.connections.mysql2.strict', true);
\Config::push('database.connections.mysql2.engine', null);

/** Opcion 2 usando el helper config() */
config(['database.connections.mysql2.driver' => 'mysql']);
config(['database.connections.mysql2.host' => '127.0.0.1']);
config(['database.connections.mysql2.port' => '3306']);
config(['database.connections.mysql2.database' => 'DATABASE_MYSQL2_NAME']);
config(['database.connections.mysql2.username' => 'DATABASE_MYSQL2_USERNAME']);
config(['database.connections.mysql2.password' => 'DATABASE_MYSQL2_PASSWORD']);
config(['database.connections.mysql2.unix_socket' => '']);
config(['database.connections.mysql2.charset' => 'utf8mb4']);
config(['database.connections.mysql2.collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci']);
config(['database.connections.mysql2.prefix' => '']);
config(['database.connections.mysql2.strict' => true]);
config(['database.connections.mysql2.engine' => null]);


/** Opcion 3 Sobreescribiendo todas las connections */
$mysql2 = [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' => '3306',
    'database' => 'DATABASE_MYSQL2_NAME',
    'username' => 'DATABASE_MYSQL2_USERNAME',
    'password' => 'DATABASE_MYSQL2_PASSWORD',
    'unix_socket' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
];
$database_connections = config('database.connections');
$database_connections['mysql2'] = $mysql2;
config(['database.connections' => $database_connections]);


/** Si querés cambiar la base de datos por defecto */
config(['database.default' => 'mysql2']);
```

Podés ver mas info en este [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#accessing-configuration-values)

**Para usar distintas databases tenes que usar las connections**

No se cuantas bases de datos querés usar al mismo tiempo, pero a todos los modelos le deberías poner el [`protected $connection = 'mysql';`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) para identificar a que base corresponde y así podés identificar que connection usan.
Ojo que también tenés que usar las connection en las migraciones y si haces las consultas usando el query builder también.  Si usás eloquent ya no sería necesario porque ya lo definiste en el modelo.

Comment: Gracias mil Maru!!! Voy a probar los métodos que me sugieres y les aviso!

Comment: de nada, manteneme al tanto de si te funcionó. Al menos a mi me funcionan las 3 alternativas.   
Aunque no se si funcionan para lo que vos necesitas. Tampoco entendi muy bien como estas creando las bases de datos y reconozco q tengo intriga. ¿Son bases Mysql?